# Mixed case JSON keys don't Marshal as expected, return error

Tags: go

Code below generates this error `json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field TMP.a of type string`

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

var b = []byte(`{"a": "str", "A": 123}`)

type TMP struct {
    // A interface{} `json:"a"`
    A string `json:"a"`
    // A int `json:"A"`
}

func main() {
    var tmp TMP
    err := json.Unmarshal(b, &tmp)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

I've read through https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshal and cannot find anything that states this shouldn't work. What am I missing?

It's been asked that I clarify, and rightly so. What I'm really wondering is why when I use JSON with only 2 keys that differ in uppercase/lowercase why Unmarshal is not keeping the case I've provided in the struct json tag.

Comment: Doesn't make sense, Adrian.  The JSON field `a` _is_ a string.  It's trying to unmarshal field `A` into the string, when the documentation clearly says that if tagged and matches, only that _exact_ field name will be used.  `Unmarshal matches incoming object keys to the keys used by Marshal (either the struct field name or its tag), preferring an exact match but also accepting a case-insensitive match.`  Honestly, this feels like a bug.

Comment: I misread the question. This is an unfortunate edge case that isn't handled well by `encoding/json`, which is effectively case-insensitive. You might [post a bug](https://github.com/golang/go/issues) for this

Comment: It might help to clarify in your question that the issue is due to having two keys in the JSON which differ only in case; that is not immediately clear on reading it.

Comment: Actually it looks like there's already an open issue for this: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14750

Comment: I should have clarified the question better, thank you all for helping me with this. Seems it's a bug or at last a consideration on the goteam to change this.

Answer (score -1):

First of all change the names of your fields. Since they have same name only uppercase A and lowercase a. So when go try to marshal the fields it is unable to recognize between the fields.

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
)

var b = []byte(`{"a": "str", "B": 123}`)

type TMP struct {
  // A interface{} `json:"a"`
  A string `json:"A"`
  B int `json:"B"`
}

func main() {
  var tmp TMP
  err := json.Unmarshal(b, &tmp)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
  }
  fmt.Println(tmp)
}
```

As the error says

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go struct field TMP.A of type int

even if you try to pass both fields like below it will give same error

```
var b = []byte(`{"a": "str", "A": 123}`)

type TMP struct {
  // A interface{} `json:"a"`
  a string `json:"a"`
  A int `json:"A"`
}
```

Comment: _Not_ what he's asking.  He's saying that in the case that two JSON fields differ only by case, specifying a field with exact case match does _not_ do a case-sensitive match to the JSON being unmarshalled.  This actually does not match the documentation of the package.  Is this good practice on the JSON side?  Almost certainly not (are JSON's even considered case sensitive to begin with?).  But it _does_ violated the text of the documentation.

Comment: Got confused he is asking why is not mentioned in go documentation. If anyone reads the question he will not able to recognize that. Sorry @Kaedys. This question is not for SO. because it is an opinion based question.

Comment: Not really opinion based.  He's asking why the package behaves this way when the documentation clearly says it shouldn't.  It's either a bug or the documentation needs to be clarified.  This doesn't fall under the category of an opinion question.

Comment: It's not opinion-based, the documentation doesn't match the observed behavior. It's acutally a [defect](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/14750). And while the spec doesn't specify if JSON object keys are case-sensitive or not, but everything else I can find seems to imply it's case-sensitive in most implementations.

Comment: @Adrian where did you find similar implementation you said `but everything else I can find seems to imply it's case-sensitive in most implementations`. Seriously I have also got confused like you with the question first :)

Comment: I _looks_ like what is happening is that it's looping over the JSON fields, and for each field, looking for an exact match.  If one is not found, it looks for inexact match, and only _then_ moves on to the next field.  This could be fixed by looping over each field looking for an exact match, and only once _all_ fields have been checked, look for inexact matches for remaining fields.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, there are JSON parsers in practically every language on earth.

Answer (score -1):

The real problem is that you're trying to unmarshal int to a string field. Error will occur even if you remove the `"a": "str"`, and will work fine if you double quote the `123`

What is a little funny, however, is that the case is ignored with only one field. Changing your struct to:

`type TMP struct {
    // A interface{}`json:"a"
    `A string`json:"a"
    `B int`json:"A"
`}`

also works.

Comment: _sigh_.  He's trying to unmarshal `"str"`, which is a string.  It's tagged to use the lowercase `a` in the struct def.